# .htaccess RewriteRule, remove URL Segment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove 'beta' from my url via .htacess. Tried several different iterations with no luck. Here is my current .htaccess.

Update:
My URL is http://pfdev.domainname.dev/beta/galleries.

My current rewrite below, works like I want it as it's removing index.php from http://pfdev.domainname.dev/beta/index.php/galleries. I have found several questions answered regarding the same issue, but applying them here hasn't worked for me yet.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the URL are you entering in browser and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a redirect rule to remove `/beta/` from URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /beta/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!beta/).*)$ beta/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```